# How to change text to digits and save into array in Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to save price data to an Excel file. I got the data from a website as text, and now I want to create an array with the data in it. My code thus far looks like this:

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    my_prices = []
    prices = data.find_all("example", {"class":"example"})
    index = 0
    for price in prices:
       print prices[index].text
       index += 1
```

My output looks like this:

```
€2,75
€9,00
€17,50
€2,75
€3,00
€2,50
€2,75
€4,00
€4,00
€0,50
€2,50
€2,50
€3,25
€2,50
€2,50
€2,50
€2,50
€2,50
€4,50
€2,50
€2,00
€4,00
€10,50
€16,50
```

If tried to ad an array in the for loop, but I can't figure out how. I'm a beginner in Python! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: You have to append to array like `my_prices.append(price.text)` in for loop.

Comment: There is no need to get `price` based on index as you are doing in for loop `prices[index]` when you run for loop, you already got object from array, and you can perform direct operation on that like `price.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the "example" prices and extract the text for each price:

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
my_prices = [price.text for price in data.find_all("example", {"class":"example"})]
```

Now your question is how to change the text to digits. If you want to retain them as strings then you can strip off the currency symbol and optionally the comma could be replaced with a decimal point if that makes sense in your locale. This method uses `unicode.translate()` in Python 2:

```
trans_table = {ord(u'\u20ac'): None, ord(u','): u'.'}
my_prices = [price.text.translate(trans_table)
                for price in data.find_all("example", {"class":"example"})]
```

If you want them as floats:

```
my_prices = [float(price.text.translate(trans_table))
                for price in data.find_all("example", {"class":"example"})]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try remove the `€` and replace `,` by `.`

```
values =[]    
for price in prices:
   values.append(prices[index].text.strip('€').replace(',','.'))
   index += 1
values_to_decimal = map(float, values) # convert values to float
```

if only need save in list with commas `,`

```
values =[]    
for price in prices:
   values.append(prices[index].text.strip('€'))
   index += 1
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, That simple You have created that list "my_prices" use that.

Your Code :

```
.
.
.
my_price=[]
for price in prices:
       print prices[index].text
       index += 1
```

Your Code(Updated By Me):

```
.
.
.
my_price=[]
for price in prices:
       values=prices[index].text.strip('€').replace(',','.')
       my_price.append(float(values))
       index += 1 
print(my_price)
```

All the prices are stored in "my_prices" array. 
Hope! It helped!